# Odd behavior when rendering string with DOT in Jinja2

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

This is my code:

```
file = 'http://www.example.com/cdn/.eJwdyjsKksjdbf-sjhdfb-kajsfbnksj'

link = '%s/cdn/%s' % (self.base_url, file)
app.log.debug('link is: %s' % link)
return template.render(link_text=link_text, link=link)
```

Here the output of the log is as below:

```
2016-06-22 05:37:23,268 - app:log - DEBUG - 330 - 106622  - Thread-6 - link is: http://www.example.com/cdn/.eJwdyjsKksjdbf-sjhdfb-kajsfbnkshdbhj
```

But the output of `template.render` for the link part is:

```
<div height=\\"40px\\" style=\\"width: 189px; height: 43px; line-height: 40px; background-color: #5c9eef; border-radius: 4px; text-align: center;\\">\\n                 
    <a href=\\"http://www.example.com/cdn/\\" style=\\"text-decoration: none; font-weight: 300; line-height: 42px; font-family: tahoma; font-size: 15px;   
    letter-spacing: 1px; color: #fff;\\">Download File</a>\\n
```

The generated link is missing the part with `.`! Does that mean `jinja2` behaves odd on this character?! Is there anything I could do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark your html as safe, otherwise Jinja performs autoescaping. This is as simple as:

```
from jinja import Markup

...
return template.render(link_text=link_text, link=Markup(link))
```

The other way you can do this is from the html template itself - just mark the variable as safe:

```
{{ my_variable | safe }}
```